# How to save a log of all psql queries AND the results

Tags: sql, psql

This question is similar to:
[psql - write a query and the query's output to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20432998/psql-write-a-query-and-the-querys-output-to-a-file)

However, their syntax doesn't work.

When I open a psql session from the command line, I'd like to save both the queries sent and the result.

The below code saves queries, but not output:

```
psql -h host -U username -p port -d database -L ~/file_to_save_output.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just redirect the output (`STDOUT`) using the `>` symbol like below. Redirection works in both Unix and Windows command prompt.

```
psql -h host -U username -p port -d database -L ~/file_to_save_output.txt > output.txt
```

From [Postgres Doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-psql.html)

> --echo-queries
>
> Copy all SQL commands sent to the server to standard output as well.
>   This is equivalent to setting the variable ECHO to queries.

So in order to get query + query results to a **single file**,

```
psql -h host -U username -p port -d database --echo-queries -L output_queries_and_results.txt
```

Additionally you can save queries and query results **in separate files**,

```
psql -h host -U username -p port -d database --echo-queries -L output_queries_only.txt -o output_results_only.txt
```

**Note:** The first method will still show queries and query results in terminal, the second will output all results to the file and won't show in the terminal.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work. I'm wondering if it's because I'm on Redshift, which runs PSQL 8.0.2. Any thoughts @rahul?

Comment: No idea buddy but I am surprised why it wouldn't work. it should definitely work if you are running the command from cmmand prompt. If you are using any third party tool then no idea. Sorry.

Comment: thanks for all your help. For some reason, the ">" doesn't even allow the connection to be made... if I use "-L" instead, I can connect and the queries end up being sent, but not the results. This is puzzling

Comment: I think it works w/ -L (as I mentioned). The trick was that you have to quit your session (OR enter another query) before the it writes the latest results. If it works on your machine, I can update the solution.

Comment: Check my edited answer (the `EDIT:` part). See if that works for you.

Comment: @dchandler, feel free to edit my answer if the edite adds value to it.